# Is it sound to transmute a MaybeUninit<[T; N]> to [MaybeUninit<T>; N]?

Tags: rust

Is the following code sound?

```
#![feature(maybe_uninit)]
use std::mem;
const N: usize = 2; // or another number
type T = String; // or any other type

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        // create an uninitialized array
        let t: mem::MaybeUninit<[T; N]> = mem::MaybeUninit::uninitialized();
        // convert it to an array of uninitialized values
        let mut t: [mem::MaybeUninit<T>; N] = mem::transmute(t);
        // initialize the values
        t[0].set("Hi".to_string());
        t[1].set("there".to_string());
        // use the values
        println!("{} {}", t[0].get_ref(), t[1].get_ref());
        // drop the values
        mem::replace(&mut t[0], mem::MaybeUninit::uninitialized()).into_initialized();
        mem::replace(&mut t[1], mem::MaybeUninit::uninitialized()).into_initialized();
    }
}
```

I should note that miri runs it without problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Correction:** The answer below still holds in the general case, but in the case of `MaybeUninit` there are a few handy special cases about memory layout that makes this actually safe to do:

First, the documentation for `MaybeUninit` has a [layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#layout) section stating that

> `MaybeUninit<T>` is guaranteed to have the same size and alignment as `T`.

Secondly, the language reference says this about [array layouts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#array-layout):

> Arrays are laid out so that the `nth` element of the array is offset from the start of the array by `n * the size of the type` bytes. An array of `[T; n]` has a size of `size_of::<T>() * n` and the same alignment of `T`.

This means that the layout of `MaybeUninit<[T; n]>` and the layout of `[MaybeUninit<T>; n]` are the same.

---

**Original answer:**

From what I can tell, this is one of those things that are likely to work but not guaranteed, and *may* be subject to compiler-specific or platform-specific behavior.

[`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html) is defined as follows in the [current source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/d049c7baa701c4128507/src/libcore/mem.rs#L1097-L1103):

```
#[allow(missing_debug_implementations)]
#[unstable(feature = "maybe_uninit", issue = "53491")]
pub union MaybeUninit<T> {
    uninit: (),
    value: ManuallyDrop<T>,
}
```

Since it's not marked with the `#[repr]` attribute (as opposed to for instance [`ManuallyDrop`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/d049c7baa701c4128507/src/libcore/mem.rs#L938-L944)), it's in the default representation, of which the reference [says this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-default-representation):

> Nominal types without a repr attribute have the default representation. Informally, this representation is also called the rust representation.
>
> **There are no guarantees of data layout made by this representation.**

In order to transmute from `Wrapper<[T]>` to `[Wrapper<T>]`, it must be the case that the memory layout of `Wrapper<T>` is *exactly* the same as the memory layout of `T`. This is the case for a number of wrappers, such as the previously mentioned `ManuallyDrop`, and those will usually be marked with the `#[repr(transparent)]` attribute.

But in this case, this is not *necessarily* true. Since `()` is a zero-size type, it's likely that the compiler will use the same memory layout for `T` and `MaybeUninit<T>` (and this is why it's working for you), but it is also possible 
 that the compiler decides to use some other memory layout (e.g. for optimization purposes), in which case transmuting will not work anymore.

---

As a specific example, the compiler may chose to use the following memory layout for `MaybeUninit<T>`:

```
+---+---+...+---+
| T         | b |     where b is "is initialized" flag
+---+---+...+---+
```

According to the above quote, the compiler is allowed to do this. In this case, `[MaybeUninit<T>]` and `MaybeUninit<[T]>` have different memory layouts, since `MaybeUninit<[T]>` has one `b` for the entire array, while `[MaybeUninit<T>]` has one `b` for each `MaybeUninit<T>` in the array:

```
MaybeUninit<[T]>:
+---+...+---+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+---+
| T[0]      | T[1]      | … | T[n-1]    | b |
+---+...+---+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+---+
Total size: n * size_of::<T>() + 1

[MaybeUninit<T>]
+---+...+---+----+---+...+---+----+...+---+...+---+------+
| T[0]      |b[0]| T[1]      |b[1]| … | T[n-1]    |b[n-1]|
+---+...+---+----+---+...+---+----+...+---+...+---+------+
Total size: (n + 1) * size_of::<T>()
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if I use `MaybeUninit<[MaybeUninit<T>]>`?

Comment: @llogiq No, it shouldn't. I've added a specific example to try to clarify example what I meant here.

Comment: @llogiq Apparently I overlooked a part of the documentation for `MaybeUninit` when I originally wrote my answer. I seemed to have been originally wrong (at least in the specific case of `MaybeUninit`), and I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I think `MaybeUninit` has been `#[repr(transparent)]` since Rust 1.37: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#libraries-25